# How to setup an HTTPS Endpoint to receive json files and make the most recent json file available via a REST-API in real time

Tags: azure, rest, https, iot

An IoT device generates measurements every 20 to 40s and needs to push the data (a json file, <1kB) to a HTTPS Endpoint with a key for authentication. The most recent json file must be made available via a REST-API with another key authentication. The data must be more or less real-time (no delay >30s).

Ideally, the setup is scalable (and affordable) to receive measurements from multiple IoT devices and makes the measurements available either on different APIs or with a way to select the measurement based on an ID.

I checked out Azure Event Hub and Event Grid, but I don’t know if I’m on the right track. Any guidance on the Azure platform or any other suitable platform is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's something more complicated than you're mentioning, then I'd go with something cheap and simple like:

- `HttpTrigger` POST Azure Function to receive the JSON. Store it in an Azure Blob storage container.
- `HttpTrigger` GET Azure Function to serve the latest JSON, by retrieving it from the same Blob storage.
- Authenticate by having Middleware in the Azure Function, using whatever authentication implementation suits you best.

...if it's really as simple as you state! If cold-start latency (a few seconds) isn't an issue, and it's not millions of requests per day, then you could run it for free in a Consumption Plan resource. And Blob Storage is also very cheap too.

### Edit - request for info on storing/retrieving from Blob

Staying with the principle of using Azure Functions and Blob, and assuming you're using .NET 8 isolated functions. I'll assume you use a simple header token as authentication (this may/not be sufficient - it's beyond scope of here.)

First you'll need to set up in `Program.cs`

- Dependency Injection for the Azure Blob libraries
- Add your authentication class into the Middleware pipeline (this is just 1 option, there are others)

Here's an example:

```cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(worker =>
    {
        worker.UseMiddleware<AuthMiddleware>(); // Name of your auth class
    })
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services
            .AddAzureClients(configureClients =>
            {
                configureClients.AddBlobServiceClient(Environment
                    .GetEnvironmentVariable("YourBlobStorageResource")); // Wherever your Blob Container is going
            });
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

Then in your Azure Function endpoint class, you can take a `BlobServiceClient` as a constructor dependency, and use that to store your JSON. I've not shown the corresponding `get` function, but I'm sure you can figure that out based on the `post` one.

```cs
public class MyFunctions
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly BlobServiceClient _blob;
 
    public MyFunctions(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MyFunctions>();
        _blob = blobServiceClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(blobServiceClient));
    }

    [Function(nameof(PostIoTData))]
    public async Task<HttpResponseData> PostIoTData([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "your-route/{iotId}")] HttpRequestData req, string iotId)
    {
        var container = _blob.GetBlobContainerClient(iotId); // Assuming you have a container per IoT
        await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
        var blob = container.GetBlobClient("latest-data.json"); // Or if you want a history, maybe this would be a unique filename

        // ...then write your json to the Blob.
        // ...and return an HttpResponseData
    }
}
```

Finally, your `AuthMiddleware` class could be something like this, assuming you're just checking a simple header:

```cs
public class AuthMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public AuthMiddleware(ILogger<AuthMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var requestData = await context.GetHttpRequestDataAsync();

        IEnumerable<string>? apiKeyValues;
        if (requestData?.Headers.TryGetValues("Api-Key", out apiKeyValues) == true)
        {
            string? apiKey = apiKeyValues?.SingleOrDefault();
            if (apiKey != null && Guid.TryParse(apiKey, out _) == true)
            {
                // Validate your API key here.

                // If it's authorised, then...
                await next(context);
            }
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Not authorised");
    }
}
```

### Notes

This is definitely not the only way to achieve your requirements, but it fits the requirements you've given so far. Hope it gives you some interesting points to consider.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable feedback. I set up an API with a POST functionalities following azure/api-management/import-and-publish guide.

Can you provide additional information about how to push the json into a Blob Storage und retrieve it with via an API? I'm unclear how to enable API access via a token (no AUTH2 support from the IoT device).

Your support is highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: OK sure. I've edited my post to give some code samples based on the simple approach I suggested.